# Query on updating a Config file

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I am new to scripting and would need assistance in one of my requirement.

I have a config file having below information

```
Run=YES
```

I want to update the value to "No" through script. Below is the script I used.

```
config_file=/Home/config
sed -e '/\(^Run=\).*/ S//\1No/' $config_file
```

The script is not updating the value. Can you assist.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "is not updating the value". If you mean that the `/Home/config` file is not changed - that's how `sed` works by default, i.e. it reads the input file, applies the changes, and outputs the result to the console.

You can either redirect the output to a different file and then rename to overwrite, or - if your `sed` supports this - use the `-i` flag for "in-place" editing of the file.

In short:

- either

  ```bsh
  sed -e '/\(^Run=\).*/ S//\1No/' "$config_file" > "$config_file.bup"
  mv "$config_file.bup" "$config_file"
  ```
- or

  ```bsh
  sed -e -i '/\(^Run=\).*/ S//\1No/' "$config_file"
  ```